# Data Store is Nil

Tags: arrays, swift, datastore

I am using a Data Store to store events. I can see the data being stored when I call createEvent. When I call saveChanges, my array is showing as nil, and I can't figure out why. Here is the relevant code.

```
class EventStore {

    var allEvents = [Event]()
    let eventArchiveURL: URL = {
        let documentsDirectories =
            FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        let documentDirectory = documentsDirectories.first!
        print ("Directory ================ \(documentDirectory)")

        return documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("events.plist")
    }()
    
    init() {
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: eventArchiveURL)
            let unarchiver = PropertyListDecoder()
            let events = try unarchiver.decode([Event].self, from: data)
            allEvents =  events
        } catch {
            print("Error reading in saved events: \(error)")
        }
    }
        
    @discardableResult func createEvent(date: Date?, event: String) -> Event {
        let newEvent = Event(date: date, event:event)
        allEvents.append(newEvent)
        print("Added \(newEvent.date) and \(newEvent.event) to all Events........")
        dump(allEvents)

        return newEvent
    }
    
    func removeEvent(_ event: Event) {
        if let index = allEvents.firstIndex(of: event) {
            allEvents.remove(at: index)
        }
    }
    
    func saveChanges() -> Bool {
        print("Saving events to: \(eventArchiveURL)")
        dump(allEvents)
        
        do {
            let encoder = PropertyListEncoder()
            let data = try encoder.encode(allEvents)
            try data.write(to: eventArchiveURL)
            print("Saved the events")
            return true
        } catch let encodingError {
            print("Error encoding allEvents: \(encodingError)")
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried comparing my code to an example program for Big Nerd Ranch and everything seems correct. I expect to see all the elements in the array saved to my plist when I call saveChanges.

Comment: What do you mean with “ my array is showing as nil”? Do you get an error when saving or what happens?

Comment: When I call the saveChanges function, the dump(allEvents) line returns nil.

Comment: I've narrowed it down to how I am accessing my eventStore from my SceneDelegate. I realized that I had not connected to my ViewController properly, so I wasn't pulling the Data Store. Any guidance on how to access the ViewController from the SceneDelegate?